# Unable to display a value from a SQL Datasource in a ListView EmptyDataTemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview

I am unable to display a value from a SQL Datasource in a ListView .

Working with the code below, the value held in 'equipment_attrib_value_id' in the  displays fine (so the ahref link works) but in the  the value held in 'equipment_attrib_value_id' is not displayed, meaning the link simply points to AddAttribValue.aspx?EquipmentID=20&HeadingID=

(so no value is on the end of the HeadingID)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="modify" SortExpression="modify">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListViewAttribModify" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceAttribValues">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td style="font-size:x-small;">
            <a href="EditAttribValue.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("equipment_attrib_value_id") %>">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <table ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
            <tr ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
        </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table id="Table2" style="">
            <tr>
            <td style="font-size:x-small;">
                <a href="AddAttribValue.aspx?EquipmentID=<%=Request.QueryString("id") %>&HeadingID=<%# Eval("equipment_attrib_heading_id") %>">Add</a>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The value held in 'equipment_attrib_value_id' does exist because it is presenting itself correctly in the . What is preventing me using the same value in the  and more importantly, how do I fix it / work around it?

Answer (score 0):

The EmptyDataTemplate will only display when there is no data bound to the ListView (e.g. you have bound an empty collection), so your eval is bound to return null as there is simply no record.

Comment: That makes logical sense but it must know the value of the row it's presenting in the list (the 'equipment_attrib_value_id' value). Is there a better way for me to retrieve this value in order to create my custom "Add" link?

Comment: The problem you have is that the EmptyDataTemplate will only display when there are no rows at all.  From MSDN "Gets or sets the user-defined content for the empty template that is rendered when a ListView control is bound to a data source that does not contain any records".  Given that you want to add a row and the guess that equipment_attrib_value_id is the primary key in the table you want to add the row to then I suspect you simply don't need the value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ben, you also highlighted a typo in my code which I've just now edited in the original post too. The value of 'equipment_attrib_value_id' is indeed the primary key, but (as per now-edited code) I need to create an "AddAttribValue.aspx" link which contains the value 'equipment_attrib_heading_id' so my Add pages knows which HeadingID to assign too. The value of equipment_attrib_heading_id is included in the same SELECT statement further up, but as the equipment_attrib_value_id doesn't exist, neither can the equipment_attrib_heading_id !  I think I need a lie down.

Comment: If you posted you SQL tables i could possibly provide an answer but it's difficult to understand what the correct solution is with no understanding of your data structures.